# append to array inside another array python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

Basically I have data that spans several years and I would like to append all this data into an array using one array and the years as keys. Then would would like to callback all the data in the array relevant to a particular year by just calling the date.

for example:

all data that is relevant to 2016 would be as such

```
array[2016].append('1')
array[2016].append('2')
```

and then when the date changes to 2015

```
array[2015].append('3')
array[2015].append('4')
```

and then call the data

```
print array[2016]
1,2
```

Comment: That looks fine so far.  What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Do you  want a dict with lists as values?

Comment: I think a defaultdict will work better than any array   logic https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: why not use a dictionary?

Comment: I used BHAT IRSHAD example.  Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

How about python dictionaries:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = defaultdict(list)
>>> data[2016].append('1')
>>> data[2016].append('2')
>>> data[2015].append('3')
>>> data[2015].append('4')
>>> print data[2016]
['1', '2']
>>> print data[2015]
['3', '4']
```

Comment: Excellent.  Just what I was looking for.